# Code Igniter blank page with no error display even though display errors are on

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.4 version. My production server environment is "PHP Version 5.5.26-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1", Apache, Ubuntun.

Display error is on server wide. I've turned it on from the index.php like following code as well

```
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING | E_DEPRECATED));
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING | E_DEPRECATED));
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

Apache error.log

```
[Thu Jul 09 06:25:10.623268 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5000] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 09 06:25:10.623313 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5000] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Jul 09 11:18:37.211428 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5000] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jul 09 11:18:38.742472 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29818] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 09 11:18:38.742552 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29818] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Jul 09 12:11:37.699200 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29818] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jul 09 12:11:38.517693 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3072] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 09 12:11:38.517797 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3072] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Jul 09 12:19:15.599384 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3072] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jul 09 12:19:16.423490 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3819] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 09 12:19:16.423584 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3819] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Except this, there's nothing in there. And I don't think it's related.

But no errors were shown and totally blank page. It's running fine on other production server environment as well as localhost.

What should I check and how should I resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you check your apache log???

Comment: Check your source code for any *exit()* or *die()* statements

Comment: @Saty, I've just checked the apache log, there's nothing related with that :/. I even turn on logs from config.php of CodeIgniter, in log folder it doesn't create anything too

Comment: Did you turn error reporting on directly in you php.ini too? (and restart the server after you change it)

Comment: @DamienPirsy, Yeap, It's already restarted and display_error is on as well.

Comment: Do one thing use `echo die();` and check where it fails, start if from main `index.php` file !!

Comment: Does apache have permission to access the files on the server?  it could be a permissions issue.  Fairly common one, I've found.

Comment: @Saty, it doesn't show anything at all.

Comment: @gabe3886, as in? Currently owner group of file and folder is root root

Comment: What your console say i mean `500 or 404`??

Comment: @Saty, nothing. Just blank.

Comment: @knightrider try setting the group to be www-data `sudo chown -R :www-data /location/of/codeigniter`.  Also make sure the group has read/write permissions so you can add/modify files and logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the comments on the question, this appears to be a permissions issue, as the folder (and possibly/probably) the files within are assigned to user root and group root.

You'll need to allow Apache to access the files and folders in order to get it running.  There's two ways of doing this:

1. Set the user and/or group to be www-data by running `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/codeigniter' (for user and group), or remove the :www-data part for only setting the user, or use :www-data to only set the group.  If the group is set, you'll need to make sure the group has read and write access to the folders and files (`sudo chmod g+rw /path/to/codeigniter`).
2. **Note: this is not the best way as it can open up all kinds of security issues** set the permissions to the file and folder structure to be 777 (everyone can read, write and execute) by doing `sudo chmod -r 0777 /path/to/codeigniter`

Comment: Not a problem.  It's one of the most common problems I come across.

Answer (score 0):

check error log by ssh tail command like

tail -f /var/log/httpd/error.log

here you can go to httpd folder and then ls and see what exact name of error log and then use tail command to view that log file.

to go to httpd folder just write cd /var/log/httpd and then ls to check error_log file name.

Comment: There's only apache2 folder in var/log, and there's only access.log but there's nothing related inside

Comment: please check this link http://www.codeasite.com/index.php/linux-a-apache/94-how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files

Comment: in this scenario, i think you have to use hit and trial method means put echo "test"; exit;  on top of controller function and run it and if test is written on browser and then move further to check where it did not work.